# Converting POJO to JSON for object comparison?

Tags: java, json, pojo

**Background:** API is used to update/insert some entries into a database.
**Current logic:** The API/service first fetches the already existing(if any, for the combination of arguments provided by the client) **record/entry object** from the database and then checks if **some predefined client specific attributes values** that the client sent in the request object are already there in the **record/entry object**. If so, it **doesn't proceed with update database call for that particular scenario** otherwise goes for update call.

**Issue:** We have multiple clients and each client wants to check a different combination of attributes present the request object.

**Constraints:**

- The attributes are deeply nested.
- The order of attributes present in **request object** maybe different from the **record/entry object.**

Now we want to generalize this attribute comparison, wanted to understand the following:

- What different ways are there to achieve this?
- Does converting the objects to JSON using some library and then comparing, a good way? What could be the challenges?

```
class ClientContributedPojo {
 private List<DeeplyNestedClassA> attrA;
 private List<DeeplyNestedClassB> attrB;
 private List<DeeplyNestedClassC> attrC;
 private List<DeeplyNestedClassD> attrD;
}
```

```
class DataBaseRecord {
 private DeeplyNestedClassP attrP;
 private DeeplyNestedClassQ attrQ;
 private List<DeeplyNestedClassA> attrA;
 private List<DeeplyNestedClassD> attrD;
 private List<DeeplyNestedClassC> attrC;
}
```

Now **clients** wants to compare values in following way:

- client1 - attrA, attrD
- client2 - attrB, attrC
- client3 - attrA, attrB, attrD

Currently the logic of this comparison is too tightly coupled to clients(each requiring a different function), we want to generalise it.

Comment: Maybe a concrete example would help. It looks like you want for each client to have different expressions that, applied to the record object, yields the values to compare. You can use a conversion to JSON and use JSON pointers, or maybe something like JXPath can save you:https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jxpath/users-guide.html.

Comment: This sounds like a good fit for [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/).

Comment: @JP Moresmau I have added the example.